# Where to put Laravel Methods that help the controller and model get data and process it?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am building a PHP Laravel v5.3 app that will function as a Notebook with Notes and Tags as well as Note revisions/versions which can be used to restore a Note record to an older version of the Note.

It is basically an EverNote Clone in PHP similar to the open source Project Paperwork but will not be using AngularJS.

Based on that description above, my project has these `Models`:

- Notebook
- Note
- NoteVersion
- NoteTag

---

I have these Controller Classes to process the incoming HTTP Requests to the server **Notebooks**, **Notes**, and **NoteVersions**.

I need to have a function that will query the database for 2 NoteVersion records and return them as part of a JSON response which will be used as part of a view to show a comparison of 2 Note Versdions so a user can see the difference between the 2 records.

So assuming I add a new Controller Method to build this view, if I don't want the COntroller Method to handle the whole process of query the Database and doing all the work, what type of File would I put a function like that in  instead?

Assume the function I want to build is like this:

```
get2NoteVersionsForComparison($currentNoteId, $oldNoteId);
```

In my controller method I want to call this method `get2NoteVersionsForComparison($currentNoteId, $oldNoteId)` and have it return a JSON response.

So where best would my `get2NoteVersionsForComparison($currentNoteId, $oldNoteId)` method live at?

A Repository, Model, ServioceProvider?

Answer (score 1):

I like to create a new project or company-specific folder and create a class in that folder. So, for example, `App\Acme\MyClassFile.php` would be the location. Create classes that do everything else. Sort of like a repository, if you will. But where doesn't matter as long as you use proper namespacing.